Discrepancy between the height shown for a DOM element and its actual screen size
I don't know if that is only appears in VS Code, but that's the only place I see this effect (and I'm trying to design a web page with the same metrics):
The height of a file tree row is actually larger than what the dev tools report. To replicate:

Open VS Code with a project so that you get a file tree in the sidebar.
Open the dev tools Help -> Toggle Developer Tools.
Inspect any of the entries in the tree using the picker tool.

For me the DOM inspector says this item has a height of 22px:

However, it's actually significantly larger (check the small size badge at the left border of the screen loupe):

Also visually it's clear that this is not only 22px in height.
I have checked if there's a transformation applied to any of the parent DOM elements, but I couldn't find any. There's no viewport scaling and the zoom in VS Code is set to standard. So I'm pretty baffled how that can be. What else could explain the different sizes?
I can assure the screen loupe shows the correct size, as I can verify in other browser windows that the DOM element height and the value shown for that element in the loupe are the same. Only for VS Code they differ.
